# Connect Android studio emulator with Visual studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-studio, android-emulator, android-volley

I have an API in my local server visual studio 2019 And an Android app running on my android studio emulator. How can I connect both with each other? I want to debug my API calls.

How can I do this?

Let me know. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: https://localhost:44339/api/Airport/endPoint


API is running ok on my browser but not in my emulator